# How to deserizlize json to polimorphic class?

Tags: java, jackson

I need deserialize JSON to class depends on type of one of the property.
I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "type":"text",
   "message": "Hello"
}
```

and I have the following `Enum`:

```
public enum MyEnumType {
    TEXT("text"),
    DATE("date")
    private final String type;
    MyEnumType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and I have the `Abstract` class shown as the following:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    public MyEnumType type;
}
```

and I have some of classes which extends `MyClass`

```
public class TextMessage extends MyClass {
    public String message;
}

public class DateMessage extends MyClass {
    ...
}
```

and I need to write some code looks like the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass instance = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

and have to get instance depends on `type` property, if `type` is `TEXT` to deserialize to `TextMessage` class otherwise to `DateMessage` class.

How can I do this? Can you give me some ideas or examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: Google for Jackson + @JsonTypeInfo, that should get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is a little bit confuse but maybe you could do something similar to this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String json = "{\"type\":\"text\", \"message\": \"Hello\"}";

        // create ObjectMapper instance
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MainObj mo = objectMapper.readValue(json, MainObj.class);

        System.out.println("type: " + mo.getType());

        MyClass instance = null;
        if (mo.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
            // Do it for the 'text'
        } else {
            // Do it for the 'date'

        }
    }

}

class MainObj {
    private String type = "";
    private Object message = null;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Object getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(Object message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
    }
}
```